# Creating new cocoa touch file in Xcode does not indent the file with project settings

Tags: swift, xcode

I have my project's indentation set to tabs with 2 spaces but every time I create a new `Cocoa Touch Class` in my project it is generate with indents of 4 spaces, could someone please help me fix this?

I know that I can just do `cmd+a` and `ctrl+i` to properly format it again but just wanted to know if it can be automatically formatted when a new file is added.

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I think you should file a bug report with Apple. The problem here is that the spaces are hard coded into the template files.

Comment: Sounds like you are right, Thanks Matt.